# Should all implementations of SHA512 give the same Hash?

Tags: hash, checksum, sha512

I am working on writing a SHA512 function.  When i check the file I am encrypting on different sources, a Linux SHA512SUM tool, a couple websites, and run it through the old source code i have for SHA512, they all give different hash values.  My thought going into this project is that all Hash algorithms will output the same hash value if implemented correctly, to be used as a check sum.  Am I wrong in thinking this? If I am wrong how would I really check to see if my work is correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's one of the basic building block of PKI: the same data block passed to a hash should always return the same hash value.

beware of the interpretation, though: the result of a SHA-2(512) hash is a block of 512 bits, not a string value so it will first be encoded for human consumption and it is therefore possible that you see what looks like visually different results when it's simply a matter of using different encodings.

Comment: For hashing the string, "Hi There", the Linux tool gives the first three numbers as "526", while the website http://hash.online-convert.com/sha512-generator has the has start as "523".  This trend continues with only really two websites agreeing.  The source code I am working with uses a form of binary to actually display the hash.  How do I know which tool to really go with?

Comment: Hashing works on bits and bytes, not text so you have to take into account the decoded version of your input. First, try it with some of the more relevant test vectors. Typically, an empty string is a good test vector but you can find many others with a simple web search.

Comment: Oh, and 'Hi There', when encoded as a straight 8bit ASCII string returns the following hash (hex-encoded): 523df363aa22c25478a478d25e6945f842509df8b77b0c755a40538a9a239ae178b3225f516bdb9e29f6d1cb7de4f2cf74e67fd85f6d9817c48890d686d51838